How to update a single database table in a separate LUW in ABAP?
I have a requirement in an existing production development to log errors. It needs to be done in multiple applications.
I created a table and called it in a method. I am calling a Function Module as starting new task to commit work.
This is done to avoid commit work in the actual application. However, in a test program I created I noticed that the system automatically calls commit work instantly when this FM is called.
In the code below, I expect 'Function Module' to be committed in the table, but it commits both 'Prog' and 'Function Module'. 'Prog' is committed instantly when the FM is called and 'Function Module' after commit work in the FM.
What other alternatives do I have? I have tried in update, background task, submit program, perform on commit. Nothing worked.
Main program:
REPORT zak_test_luw.
DATA: ls_log TYPE zdt_error_log,
      lv_tms TYPE timestampl.
    
GET TIME STAMP FIELD lv_tms.
ls_log-time_stamp = lv_tms.
ls_log-msg1 = 'prog'.
ls_log-msg2 = ''.
MOVE-CORRESPONDING sy TO ls_log.
MODIFY zdt_error_log FROM ls_log.
zdcl_utility_new=>update_logging_table( iv_msg1 = |Function Module| ).

Method:
METHOD update_logging_table.
    DATA: ls_log TYPE zdt_error_log,
          lv_tms TYPE timestampl.

    GET TIME STAMP FIELD lv_tms.
    ls_log-time_stamp = lv_tms.
    ls_log-msg1 = iv_msg1.
    ls_log-msg2 = iv_msg2.
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING sy TO ls_log.
    IF commit_work = abap_true.
      MODIFY zdt_error_log FROM ls_log.
      COMMIT WORK.
    ELSE.
      CALL FUNCTION 'ZDF_UPDATE_ERROR_LOG_TBL' STARTING NEW TASK 'LOGTABLE  '
        EXPORTING
          is_log = ls_log.
    ENDIF.
ENDMETHOD.

Function module:
FUNCTION zdf_update_error_log_tbl.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Local Interface:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(IS_LOG) TYPE  ZDT_ERROR_LOG
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------

  MODIFY zdt_error_log FROM is_log.
  COMMIT WORK.

ENDFUNCTION.


The question could be more useful for future visitors by generalizing it (title "How to run ABAP SQL in a separate database LUW") and making the example code minimal and reproducible (merge program and method/dummy demo SAP table like SCARR) as per the Help Center, and I'd then love to answer it ;-)

The problem you seem to be having is due to implicit database commits. https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abendb_commit.htm#@@ITOC@@ABENDB_COMMIT_1 . Why can't you put main session updates in update task ( call function XXX in UPDATE TASK), so that implicit DB commits doesn't update the tables directly in main session

in background task and in update task don't commit themselfs, but they only run when the calling program commits. That means you'd lose your log when there's a rollback. Perform on rollback also doesn't help, since you can't commit there, so you can't write to a database.
As far as I know, the only way to run an independen routine without commiting is raising an event (BP_EVENT_RAISE) to run a job. You can save the log to a shared buffer and pass an id to read the buffer via the job parameter (I haven't verified this myself, but I'm pretty sure export to shared buffer doesn't need a commit and the ABAP-documentation also doesn't mention it).

Thanks for your your response. I used BP_EVENT_RAISE and SHMD concept to do this and it is working like a charm

If you can control the updates in main session, below is the solution (to trigger the updates in main session using update task, that can be controlled with COMMIT WORK or ROLLBACK WORK )
REPORT ZMS_TEST_LUW.

DATA: ls_log TYPE BALM,
      ls_log1 TYPE BALM,
      lv_tms TYPE timestampl.

GET TIME STAMP FIELD lv_tms.
ls_log-lognumber = 'LOG1'.
ls_log-msgnumber = '0001'.

ls_log-time_stmp = lv_tms.
ls_log-msgv1 = 'LUW1'.
ls_log-msgv2 = ''.
MOVE-CORRESPONDING sy TO ls_log.

CALL FUNCTION 'ZMS_FM_UPD' IN UPDATE TASK
 EXPORTING is_log = ls_log.

GET TIME STAMP FIELD lv_tms.
ls_log1-lognumber = 'LOG2'.
ls_log1-msgnumber = '0001'.

ls_log1-time_stmp = lv_tms.
ls_log1-msgv1 = 'LUW2'.
ls_log1-msgv2 = ''.
MOVE-CORRESPONDING sy TO ls_log1.

CALL FUNCTION 'ZMS_FM_ASYNCH' STARTING NEW TASK 'asdf'
 EXPORTING is_log = ls_log1.

ROLLBACK WORK.

.
FUNCTION ZMS_FM_UPD.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Update Function Module:
*"
*"*"Local Interface:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(IS_LOG) TYPE  BALM
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
MODIFY balm FROM is_log.
ENDFUNCTION.

.
FUNCTION zms_fm_asynch.
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
*"*"Local Interface:
*"  IMPORTING
*"     VALUE(IS_LOG) TYPE  BALM
*"----------------------------------------------------------------------
  MODIFY balm FROM is_log.
ENDFUNCTION.

